# Is there a difference between the words "zig", "zag", and "zigzag"?

Tags: vocabulary, diction

In the book "The Green Mile" by Stephen King, a mouse is described to zig and then zag. What's the difference between the words "zigzag", "zig" and "zag"?

```
The mouse barley avoid Percy's last two jumps, first zigging and then zagging.
```

I guess I'm unclear as to the description given of what the mouse did. Is he saying the mouse first went in one direction and then went in another to avoid being jumped on?

Comment: [zigzag](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zig-zag) is a borrowing. splitting into zig and zag is just word play. They don't have individual meanings like 'left' or 'right' beyond 'zig' usually coming first.

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigzag):

> A zigzag is a pattern made up of small corners at variable angles, though constant within the zigzag, tracing a path between two parallel lines; it can be described as both jagged and fairly regular.

[image]

[Zig](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/zig?q=zig) and [zag](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/zag) as separate words can both be defined as follows;

> *noun*: a sharp change of direction in a zigzag course for example "he went round and round in zigs and zags"
>
> *verb*: make a sharp change of direction for example "we zigged to the right"

The words "zig" and "zag" mean the same thing and are both derived from "zigzag". Since the word "zigzag" essentially means "moved side to side", zig and zag are often used to clearly state that something moved one way (zig) and then the other (zag).

Comment: Just a minor point, but perhaps worth making: a _zigzag stitch_ would be very regular (as is shown in your diagram), but I would expect a mouse's _zigging and zagging_ to be much more erratic. That could be one possible differentiation between the word _zigzagging_ and phrase _zigging and zagging_, but it's heavily context dependent.

Answer (score 2):

'Zigzag' is an expression which means to dart from side to side. Sometimes people will say she zigged and then zagged, indicating she went from side to side, possibly with no apparent purpose. Taken individually the words zig and zag have no meaning, but only when used together.

Comment: Are you aware that some online dictionaries have entries for just zig or zag? For example http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zig

Comment: @Celeritas No I was not aware of that. What are the individual meanings?

Comment: From what I've red zig, zag and zigzag all have the same meaning.

Comment: @ Celeritas I suppose if you look at it like that, 'left' and 'right' have the same meaning. It is just that one is on one side the other on t'other.

Comment: @Celeritas: Indeed. The OED as well as three entries: for zig, for zag and for zigzag.

Comment: @Celeritas: You could say that a zigzag is made up of a *zig* followed by a *zag* (and repeat), but that is informal, and *zig* has no meaning outside a 'zigzag' context. (Neither does *zag*, of course)

Comment: @TimLymington I'm glad we have zigzagged our way to an answer to that little matter.

Comment: @Laure: If you're going to cite OED as an authority showing that "zig" and "zag" are separate words, it's only fair to note the definitions. ***Zig** The first syllable of **zigzag**, used in the same way as **zag** n.* Leading to ***Zag** The second syllable of **zigzag** used as a separate word (adv., v., or n.) to express a movement or direction inclined at an angle to that indicated by **zig**.* WS2 is essentially correct - the individual sub-elements have no meaning except by contrast with the other. Left/Right are objectively distinct, Zig/Zag are not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I would have thought that left was to right as zig was to zag, but I will bow to your greater status.

Comment: @WS2: Technically speaking, left/right really *are* "arbitrary", in that there could be areas within our universe (or entire "alternate universes") where they were the opposite way round. Those areas/universes would be identical to ours except from our point of view they'd be made of antimatter (as would we, from their perspective). I really like [Feynman's lecture on that topic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGsYbK-Chkg) (I laughed out loud when I first *read* the point he makes at 54m 10s there!). There's also a "local framework" for Up/Down, obviously. But definitely not for Zig/Zag.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is getting too technical for me!

Comment: @WS2: You are too modest. I'm sure you can see how up/down are "local" (if you were out in "empty" deep space, far away from even any galaxies, they wouldn't mean anything except by arbitrary opposition to each other). You might also know that DNA (almost) always has a "right-handed" thread, or that [left-handed sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagatose) tastes sweet because it triggers or taste buds much the same as ordinary sugar, but it can't be used by the digestive processes in the same way (so it's "low calorie").

Comment: @FumbleFingers But as long as a human was there, wouldn't up be in the direction of the head and down toward the feet? I mean,  I would still have a right and left hand, even in outer space, wouldn't I? As for left-handed sugar, I'll try it out on the Sainsbury's staff next time I'm there.

Comment: @WS2 - no, your head would be cephalad, not up, and feet would be caudal, not down. Up and down only refer to the orientation to the earth's (or other planetary body) horizon (or flow of water). Thus, when you lie on your back, your belly, nose and toes are up, and your derriere is down. Regarding left and right, if you were rotating, it would make no difference to anyone but yourself, as you would not be in a fixed plane. Everything would be on your left, and everything would be on your right.